# Get age between the current year and birthdate, gives **"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."**

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I need to get names who are `age >=70` from a table PERSON and Column BIRTHDATE(varchar(8)).

Just trying this query before i start doing to display age >=70.

```
select DATEDIFF (year , person.BirthDate, GETDATE()) as Age, * from person
```

This query gives

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

How should i do this? I really cant think off. Thanks

Comment: What is the format of date in `person.BirthDate`?

Comment: You cant use DATEDIFF  with varchar column. You will have to convert/cast varchar to datetime/date.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the row looks like or table schema?

Comment: @cdm person.birthdate is varchar

Comment: You're storing dates wrong if you're storing them as `varchar`. Also, it's far easier (once you've got your conversions sorted out) to query "Is this person's date of birth earlier than `today - 70 years`" than it is to find the people who are currently 70 or older. The problem with trying to use `DATEDIFF` is that it counts *transitions*. A person born on 31st December is 1 year old on the 1st of January, if you use the obvious `DATEDIFF` formulation.

Comment: @Manoj i already did cast/convert date. however, some of birthdate is null which cant be convert. So i am imagining of getting the 4 character from left then cast it to int or date and then get the datediff and display the name whoever are >= 70.  ***The requirement is i MUST NOT change any data from a real DB

Answer (score 4):

you can use the query below

```
SELECT DATEDIFF( year , Convert( datetime,person.birthdate, 120 ), GETDATE() ) as Age FROM persons
```

this is will first convert your `person.birthdate` column to date and then find the difference

Comment: But `DATEDIFF` counts *transitions*. It doesn't determine what most people would define as age. If you run the above code on 1st January this year, for a person with a birthdate of `20151231`, it will return 1. Most people don't consider someone a day old to be 1.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that date of birth column is of varchar datatype. Try convert it into datetime

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF (year , cast(person.BirthDate as datetime), 
    GETDATE()) as Age, * 
FROM 
    person
```